# What is the equivalent for pythons requests.post method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, plugins, python-requests

I try to connect to googles Perspective API in Javascript. I have tried a lot of stuff I've researched, but nothing has worked. But when I've tried it in Python, it was super easy...
So basically I need the equivalent to the following simple Python code in JavaScript. And it has to work within a browser plugin.

```
import json
import requests
api_key = '<MYAPIKEY>'
url = ('https://commentanalyzer.googleapis.com/v1alpha1/comments:analyze'+'?key='+api_key)
data_dict = {
    'comment': {'text': 'text to be checked'},
    'languages': ['en'],
    'requestedAttributes': {'TOXICITY': {}}
}
response = requests.post(url=url, data=json.dumps(data_dict))
response_dict = json.loads(response.content)
```

I am not a JavaScript expert and I really need help to solve this problem, I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Use fetch (es6) it return promise, so you might need then.

Comment: You can use fetch (or axios) to call an api:

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

```
const api_key = '<MYAPIKEY>';
const url = ('https://commentanalyzer.googleapis.com/v1alpha1/comments:analyze'+'?key='+api_key);
const data_dict = {
    'comment': {'text': 'text to be checked'},
    'languages': ['en'],
    'requestedAttributes': {'TOXICITY': {}}
};

fetch(url, { 
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(data_dict)
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    // do whatever with the data from the response
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, I am definetly closer than before. But when I log `data` it just says `[object Object]`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use fetch (or axios) like :

```
fetch(url, {
   method: "POST",
   headers: {
     Accept: "application/json",
     "Content-Type": "application/json"
   }
   body: JSON.stringify(data),
}).then(res => res.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score -2):

[fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is what your looking for, its provided by the core js module. Usage is shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).